# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. When trying to import tensorflow and keras into PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, dll, pycharm

I have been trying to install and use tensorflow for the past week and I encountered a problem when importing it along with keras in PyCharm.

CPU:Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
GPU:Intel(R) HD Graphics 630

This is what I put in the file:

```
import tensorflow
import keras
```

This is what appears in the PyCharm terminal when I run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



 File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Bob/PycharmProjects/tensorenv/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have looked up these install errors with the link they provide, but all of the answers I tried either do not work or do not apply.
Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, `keras` should be imported via `from tensorflow import keras`, does it fix your issue?

Comment: No, I tried it and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`ImportError: DLL load failed` issue is not with, how you have imported `Keras` and `tensorflow` ?

common solution for this is, you need to install/update `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64)` from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

I have answered possible other reasons and compatible configurations (i.e Tensorflow, Python, etc. version details) for windows operating system in another Stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656869/13465258). Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: @pythonmachinelearningattempt, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You