# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a simple LSTM time-series model for predicting future prices using the past prices. I am getting error while running the code. I have imported keras in my code but I have not imported tensorflow directly. It shows the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pricePredictor.py", line 29, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .load_backend import epsilon
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Shashank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I have installed tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu, tensorflow-gpu-estimator. Is there anything left to be installed before using this? Also, I do not have a lot of data for training. I have only past 1 year prices. So can I run my code on CPU if the problem is with GPU?
I have `Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620` GPU with approx. memory `4176MB`(if it is needed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't import tensorflow in python, windows 10 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319768/cant-import-tensorflow-in-python-windows-10-64-bit)

Answer (score 3):

To fix DLL load failed error, you have to download and install/update the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

If you are still facing any other issues possible reasons are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656869/13465258)

Comment: Sometimes [diagnosing the actual DLL/PYD load issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944065/tensorflow-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tensorflow-inter#69874313) could help to get the issue resolved faster

Comment: Wow - this was exact. Thx!