# Unable to import tensorflow into PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/George Adamopoulos/Desktop/All My Files/Fear Neural Net Project/Computer Vision Code/ML Zero to Hero/Part_2.py", line 1, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 41, in 
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 50, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\George Adamopoulos\Anaconda3\envs\Computer Vision Code\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the instructions from [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows).

You need to download and install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

If you are facing any other issues, possible reasons are mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319768/cant-import-tensorflow-in-python-windows-10-64-bit/61656869#61656869) for the benefit of community.

Please refer tested build configurations for windows [CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu).

Answer (score 0):

Delete it from the console and reinstall it and try adding it again.