# I installed tensorflow package but it is showing the following error, so what should i do?

Tags: tensorflow

problem in tensorflow - ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SUBHAM KUMAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\SUBHAM KUMAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\SUBHAM KUMAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "C:\Users\SUBHAM KUMAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "C:\Users\SUBHAM KUMAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a 64 bit Python if you are using 32 bit. On Windows you need to have [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0). If your issue is not resolved other possible reasons are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656869/14290681).

*Note: Python binary is installed from official sources not from Windows marketplace.*

Workaround for the above issue, you can create virtual environment on anaconda and install tensorflow as shown below

```
# Create virtual environment
conda create --name TF_VE

# When conda asks you to proceed, type y:
proceed ([y]/n)?

# Activate virtual environment
conda activate TF_VE

# Install the TF Version 
conda install tensorflow
```