# Why is the pywrap.dll missing in my Python/Tensorflow. installation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I run anything in Jupyter or VScode that involves Tensorflow, I get an error that says

"`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed."`. Apparently this means something is missing and I don't know why.
I installed with pip, my python version is 3.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

To fix DLL load failed error, you have to download and install/update the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

If you are still facing any other issues possible reasons are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656869/13465258)

Comment: Did that however nothing changed.