# Hello i'm getting error while importing tensorflow in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow

Help me

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The sp enter code here ecified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f2ccb964fe70> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
      2 from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
      3 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
      4 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gaganu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't import tensorflow in python, windows 10 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319768/cant-import-tensorflow-in-python-windows-10-64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is if you are using anaconda environment,

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7

conda activate myenv
```

then

```
pip install tensorflow
```

or

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

See if this works, or if you have bazel error, let me know I will put that install guide here as well.