# failed to load native tensorflow runtime

Tags: tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\jasim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\jasim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\jasim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\jasim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jasim\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: Need more details, e.g. tensorflow version, pip version, python version, cuda/nocuda, OS?

Comment: You need to ensure the latest MSVC redistributable and that the Python binary is installed from official sources, not from Windows marketplace. If you are still facing issue you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656869/14290681). Thanks!