# I installed tensforflow and used the command but it shows the following error

Tags: tensorflow

The code I wrote was this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

and this is the error which was given...
it would be great if someone could tell a way out

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-f05745da3b73> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

~\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
---> 39 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     40 
     41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context

~\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\saksh\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't import tensorflow in python, windows 10 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319768/cant-import-tensorflow-in-python-windows-10-64-bit)

Comment: yes this entirely resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Error message says that some DLL files failed load, this because Tensorflow package is not installed properly.
Reason might be you not installed the `MSVC 2019 redistributable` or
Your `CPU does not support AVX2 instructions`.

Install the software requirements and make sure your system meet hardware requirements mentioned on the [Tensorflow install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) document.